# use pipe for curl data

Tags: curl, pipe

I'm trying to pass the `cat` output to curl:

```
$ cat file | curl --data '{"title":"mytitle","input":"-"}' http://api
```

But `input` is literally a `-`.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a special format here, otherwise this might be what you want: http://serverfault.com/questions/313599/how-do-i-pipe-the-output-of-uptime-df-to-curl

Answer (score 234):

I spent a while trying to figure this out and got it working with the following:

```
cat data.json | curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data-binary @- http://api
```

Comment: the problem is the content of the file will be the value of `input` in the JSON data.

Comment: I keep forgetting the `@` symbol. :(

Comment: You should be aware that `-d` skips `\n` and `\r` characters. That's why I always use `--data-binary`

Comment: Looks like this also works if you use `< data.json` or a heredoc (e.g. `<< EOM`) as opposed to piping with `cat`, if you want. e.g. `curl -H 'content-type: application/json' -XPOST --data-binary @- < data.json`. Looks like `--data-raw` might also work in place of `--data-binary`, but not sure if it strips newlines.

Comment: oh, or just reading the other answers apparently just `@data.json` should work instead of piping from cat. Seems pretty flexible

Answer (score 30):

You can use the magical stdin file `/dev/stdin`

```
cat data.json | curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$(</dev/stdin)" http://api
```

Comment: And what if `/dev/stdin` is 25MB, like in my use case where I need to upload a 25MB file and 25MB of base64 text is too much for bash-arguments
 to handle?

Comment: Beware of string substitution, especially for binary data. This may subtly corrupt your data (e.g. strip a trailing newline or drop everything after a NUL).

Comment: This works perfect in bash, but yields `error when reading /dev/stdin: Input/output error` in zsh

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57285781/57357 works for zsh

Answer (score 23):

If you want to type/paste the data without escaping or polluting your bash history then, you can use this:

```bash
cat | curl --json @- https://api.example/
```

The `--json` option was added in [v7.82.0](https://curl.se/changes.html#7_82_0), so if your version is older, use this:

```bash
cat | curl --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --header 'Accept: application/json' \
    --data @- \
    https://api.example/
```

These drop you into interactive `cat` where you can input the data, directly, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> in your terminal.
You finish with a newline and a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (End-of-Transmission character), which signals to `cat` that you're done.
That data is then passed to `curl`, and you have a reusable history entry.

Comment: This is lovely, especially with new `--json` flag it becomes: `cat | curl --json @- http://api`

Comment: @tutuDajuju Thanks for the tip. I think I may have used that myself but this answer predated it.

Answer (score 17):

This should also work

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @data.json http://api
```

Using -d forces curl to implicitly use POST for the request.

Comment: Yes! Very good for use cases where the size of the data exceeds what bash arguments can handle.

Answer (score 16):

```sh
# Create the input file
echo -n 'Try  and " to verify proper JSON encoding.' > file.txt

# 1. Use jq to read the file into variable named `input` 
# 2. create the desired json
# 3. pipe the result into curl
jq -n --rawfile input file.txt '{"title":"mytitle", $input}' \
| curl -v 'https://httpbin.org/post' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d@-
```

Output:

```
  ...
  "json": {
    "input": "Try \ud83d\ude01 and \" to verify proper JSON encoding.", 
    "title": "mytitle"
  }, 
  ...
```

Notice that the contents of the input file was properly escaped for using as a JSON value.

`jq` options used:

- `--null-input/-n:`
  Don’t read any input
- `--rawfile variable-name filename`:
  This option reads in the named file and binds its contents to the given global variable.

See [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for full details.

The `-d@-` option tells curl to read the data from STDIN.

Comment: The comment "The -d@- option tells curl to read the data from STDIN." was immensely helpful.

Answer (score 7):

[Curl documentation for `-d` option](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d)

> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be done with -d, --data @foobar. When --data is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out. If you don't want the @ character to have a special interpretation use --data-raw instead.

Depending of your HTTP endpoint, server configuration, you should be good by using this format:

`curl -d @data.json http://api`

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
curl --data '{"title":"mytitle","input":"'$(cat file)'-"}' http://api
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to *wrap* the content of `input` in a JSON body, and then have that sent over with a POST request. I think that the simplest way to do that is to manipulate stdin first and then push that over to curl using `-d @-`. One way could look like this:

```
cat <(echo '{"title":"mytitle","input":"') file <(echo '"}') \
| curl -d @- http://api
```

I'm using `<(echo)` to use `cat` to merge strings and files, but there is almost certainly a better way.

Keep in mind that this does not escape the contents of `file` and that you may run into issues because of that.

Comment: Is there a way to remove the additional two newlines that were not part of `file`?

Comment: Just realized that we can use `<your_original_command> |tr -d '\n'` to remove the introduced newlines.

Comment: "echo -n" won't add the newlines