# Curl, how to include the result of a command as a parameter

Tags: git, shell, curl

I want to create a curl command that POST a release with a description that is the result from a git command.

Curl command (working):

```
 curl --request POST --data "{"description": "MY git command result should be here"}" "https://gitlab.unc.nc/api/v4/projects/$APP_GITLAB_NUMBER/repository/tags/$CI_COMMIT_TAG/release"
```

Git command (working):

```
git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --oneline
```

So how can I include the result of git command in the description ? 
As a single line command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine them with backticks ``` `` ``` or `$()`.

```
curl --request POST --data "{\"description\": \"`git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --oneline`\"}" "https://gitlab.unc.nc/api/v4/projects/$APP_GITLAB_NUMBER/repository/tags/$CI_COMMIT_TAG/release"

curl --request POST --data "{\"description\": \"$(git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --oneline)\"}" "https://gitlab.unc.nc/api/v4/projects/$APP_GITLAB_NUMBER/repository/tags/$CI_COMMIT_TAG/release"
```

May both OK.

Answer (score 0):

store the git log description in a tmp file

```
echo -n "description: ' >> git_desc 
git log $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0)..HEAD --oneline &>> git_desc
```

post data from curl

```
curl --request POST --data "@git_desc" "https://gitlab.unc.nc/api/v4/projects/$APP_GITLAB_NUMBER/repository/tags/$CI_COMMIT_TAG/release"
```

Comment: Nice! But a one line command is what OP is asking for. But this is a good solution too. @Tyvain check this link out [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583930/use-pipe-for-curl-data)