# jq command gives invalid payload with curl

Tags: curl, jq

I have a JSON list and I am trying to POST a particular key: value from the list to the slack webhook using curl. I am using jq to get the value for a specific key

This works fine:

```sh
echo {{job.message}} | jq -r '.[0] | .status'
```

This does not work:

```sh
curl -vvv -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" --data \"{\"text\":\"{{job.message}} | jq -r ''.[0] | .status''\"}\" https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx
```

`job.message` is a variable with json list

When I output the result using echo in shell, it works fine but when I use curl it show invalid payload or .key not found even though the key is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `text` value, there is no mention of the command `echo ...`, you may use a subshell to evaluate the result. Also, you can use single quote for `--data` instead of double quote to avoid escaping:

```sh
curl -vvv -X POST \
    -H "Content-type: application/json" \
    --data '{"text":"'"$(echo $job_message | jq -r '.[0].status')"'"}' \
    "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx"
```

Also you can use `jq -n` to build the JSON object:

```sh
curl -vvv -H "Content-type: application/json" \
    -d "$(jq -n --arg text $job_message '{"text": ($text | fromjson)[0].status}')" \
    "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx"
```

You can also pipe `jq` command output to the body like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25049637/2614364) and use `jq` only to build the json object:

```sh
jq -n --arg text $job_message '{"text": ($text | fromjson)[0].status}' | \
   curl -vvv -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @- "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx"
```

Comment: thank you. the second option worked for me